# Gradle task to print out files in a configuration

Tags: gradle

I'm new to Gradle and trying to convert a large Maven build over to Gradle. I'm trying to debug a dependency problem and I would like to print out all the files in a configuration. This is a multi module build and I have tried defining a task at both the top level or in the module I am interested in. In both cases, I see output from the task, but no files listed.

At the top level I tried something like this:

```groovy
task printFilesRoot {
  dependsOn 'build'
  doLast {
    println "From root, printing artifacts"
    project(":some-module").configurations.myconfig.allArtifacts.each { art -> println "Artifact: " + file }

    println "From root, printing files"
    project(":some-module").configurations.myconfig.allArtifacts.getFiles().each { file -> println "File: " + file }
  }
}
```

Within the module, I tried something similar:

```groovy
task printFilesModule {
  doLast {
    println "From module, printing artifacts"
    configurations.myconfig.allArtifacts.each { art -> println "Artifact: " + file }

    println "From module, printing files"
    configurations.myconfig.allArtifacts.getFiles().each { file -> println "File: " + file }
  }
}
```

I have tried invoking the tasks directly, or making another task (like build) dependent on one of the tasks. In every case, the only output I see is the "printing artifacts" and "printing files" statements, no actual data.

I assume I have something wrong with the way I'm trying to print out this data, but what? I'm aware that Gradle has two phases - configuration and execution. I thought that by placing my task code inside a "doFirst" or "doLast" block, that the code would be executed when the task runs, rather than during the configuration phase, but have I misunderstood something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, are you sure that you need to create a custom task?

- [`./gradlew dependencies`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html#sec:listing_dependencies) will list the dependencies in all subprojects,
- (or run `./gradlew :some-module:dependencies` to only run the task in `some-module`)
- So will a [Build Scan](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html#sec:debugging-build-scans)
- The [Project Report plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/project_report_plugin.html) can also generate reports, and the [Build Dashboard plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_dashboard_plugin.html) will aggregate them.

##### Listing all files in a configuration

[`Configuration.getAllArtifacts()`](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration.html#getAllArtifacts--) will only return [artifacts](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/dependency_management_terminology.html#sub:terminology_artifact), not dependencies. Artifacts are built by a project, and are not dependencies that your project fetches.

Since a [`Configuration`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration.html) just implements [`FileCollection`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCollection.html), which in turn implements `java.lang.Iterable<java.io.File>`, you can just iterate over the configuration.

(Since I'm not familiar with Gradle Groovy, I've adapted [an example in the Gradle docs for building a fat jar](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:creating_uber_jar_example).)

```groovy
// build.gradle

tasks.register("printFilesModule") {
  doLast {
    configurations.runtimeClasspath.each { ... }
  }
}
```

> I have tried invoking the tasks directly, or making another task (like build) dependent on one of the tasks. In every case, the only output I see is the "printing artifacts" and "printing files" statements, no actual data.

Aside from using `getAllArtifacts()`, since you're using a custom configurations named `myconfig` it's possible they're just empty and don't have any dependencies? It'd be best to stick to the configurations supplied by the standard Gradle plugins (for example, the Java Plugin creates [`implementation`, `compileOnly`, `runtimeOnly`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management), and a few more.

> I thought that by placing my task code inside a "doFirst" or "doLast" block, that the code would be executed when the task runs, rather than during the configuration phase, but have I misunderstood something here?

Nope, you have correctly defined tasks, there's no problem there.